# Jetty ResourceHandler in multi project gradle build looks in the wrong directory

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a multi project build using Gradle in the form:

```
project1
--build.gradle
--settings.gradle
project2
--src
----main
------java
--------LocalJettyRunner.java
------webapp
--------static
----------index.html
```

When I run my `LocalJettyRunner` and load `localhost:8135` I get a 404 when I am expecting my `ResourceHandler` to return my Index.html. I have debugged the `ResourceHandler.handle(...)` method it appears to be looking in my `project1/static` directory which obviously doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

---

**LocalJettyRunner**

```
public class LocalJettyRunner {}

    public void start() throws Exception {
        log.info("Starting api");

        ResourceHandler webHandler = new ResourceHandler();
        webHandler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
        webHandler.setResourceBase("static/");
        webHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});

        HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
        handlers.addHandler(webHandler);

        Server server = new Server(8135);
        server.setHandler(handlers);
        server.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new LocalJettyRunner().start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the ResourceBase to "../project2/src/main/webapp/static" seems to fix it but this shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResourceBase is an absolute path and/or URL to an absolute path.

The fact that it works without an absolute path is because of how the `new File(String).toAbsolutePath()` works.

Try looking up a resource that you know is in the ResourceBase, via the ClassPath, and then using the URL reference to set an absolute path.

Example:

Assuming you have a `src/main/resources/webroot/`, with your static content in it (such as `index.html`), then you can resolve it first, then pass it into the base resource.

```java
package jetty.resource;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;

public class ResourceHandlerExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        // Figure out what path to serve content from
        ClassLoader cl = ResourceHandlerExample.class.getClassLoader();
        // We look for a file, as ClassLoader.getResource() is not
        // designed to look for directories (we resolve the directory later)
        URL f = cl.getResource("webroot/index.html");
        if (f == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find resource directory");
        }

        // Resolve file to directory
        URI webRootUri = f.toURI().resolve("./").normalize();
        System.err.println("WebRoot is " + webRootUri);

        ResourceHandler handler = new ResourceHandler();
        handler.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));

        server.setHandler(handler);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Incidentally, you have a `src/main/webapp/` which tends to indicate a proper webapp / war file for Maven.  For a full blown webapp, it might be easier to skip `ResourceHandler` and just use `WebAppContext` directly (it wires everything up, and *does not use* `ResourceHandler`, but rather `DefaultServlet`, which is better all around for serving static files)

Comment: Any chance you could give a WebAppContext example as part of your answer please? I tried that earlier and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The `src/main/webapp` directory should be part of the as-built jar contents *and* part of the build environment's classpath during your build/test (this is easier to do in maven btw).  the classpath requirement for build/test applies to all projects that require the use of that project's tree.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `ResourceBase` to `"../project2/src/main/webapp/static"` seems to fix it although I'm not sure why the handler is looking in `project1` to begin with.